# Manual page refresh required to show user's name as logged in

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have a website running on Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) server without any errors, I installed on it a PHP script that use CodeIgniter 2.1.4 and Bootstrap.

At the top of the page, the login box works as modal popup but when someone attempts to sign in, the script reloads the page but doesn't show the user's name logged in. Only after a manual refresh of the page can the user see their name.

I've been trying to search for a solution for more than a month, including doing a new fresh install of both server and script, changing the `.htaccess` file, stopping memcached, etc.

I contacted both the owner of the script and CodeIgniter support, they told me that is probably an overload Ajax issue.

Since my script is mostly Ajax and it works fine except the login, is it possible to do the login in a different way? How could I integrate the script properly?

This is my login function (`assets/js/custom.js`):

```
function login() {
  var email = $('#loginForm [name="email"]').val();
  var pwd1 = $('#loginForm [name="password1"]').val();

  if (isEmpty(pwd1) || isEmpty(email)) {
    alert(msg_required_fields);
    return false;
  }

  $.post(base_url + 'main/login', { "email": email, "pwd1": pwd1 }, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    if (data.error == 1) {
      alert(data.msg);
    }

    if (data.error == 0) {
      document.location = base_url + 'main/reload';
    }
  }, "json");
}
```

UPDATE

I have the same problem also for the logout function:

```
    function logout()
{
    $this->admin->deleteTable('online',array('iduser' => $this->session->userdata('id')));
    $this->session->unset_userdata('id');
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    if( $this->session->userdata('facebook') == '1')
        redirect(base_url(),"main/facebook/logout");
    else
        redirect(base_url()."main/reload","refresh");
}
```

Comment: What happens if you use `window.location.href` instead of `document.location`?

Comment: @Malachi Hi, I tried and it looks like nothing has changed

Comment: Perhaps using `document.location.reload(true);` would suffice? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload

Comment: if data.error is 0 then you can redirect the page /main/reload route. Then you must write location.href = "url";

Comment: @Malachi YOU ARE AWESOME! Thank you so much, you cannot imagine how much I'm grateful. Just last favor, could you please help me also for the logout function? (I updated the question here above)

Comment: @Simone I am guessing you have a button triggered to call this logout function. What is the view of this looking like? Have you tried looking in the network panel of your browser to see the request to this logout function.

Comment: @Malachi Hi, the function is here above and the href of the li button is this:  `<a  href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>main/logout" id="navLogin"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> <?php echo ___("label_logout"); ?></a>`

Comment: @Simone That looks like it should work. The only thing that looks wrong is you have a comma in the redirect for your facebook condition. 

`redirect(base_url(),"main/facebook/logout");` should be `        redirect(base_url() . "main/facebook/logout");`


 Are you seeing anything in the network tab of your browser?

Comment: @Malachi Thanks for the fix on facebook logout, however the problem persists, I can login immediately, but on logout I need to manually refresh   the page and there are no errors on the browser console

Comment: @Simone Not sure what the problem is. I'm guessing it's going down the else condition which has the redirect with the refresh. What happens if you remove that and just have the redirect which causes a 302 redirect? so change it too `redirect(base_url()."main/reload");`

Comment: @Malachi I tried in incognito mode but it seems nothing has  changed, for the logout I need to refresh the page manually after the button touched

Comment: @Simone What about if you rewrite your logout to be like: http://kopy.io/4x0X5 You are checking the session after you call destroy.

Comment: @Malachi I just tried, but sorry it doesn't work. It's the same as before

Comment: Come here: http://tlk.io/ci-help - I'll see If I can help further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

logically the document.location object should be read-only (as you can't change the URL of a document; changing the URL loads a new document), so to be on the safe side you should rather use window.location.href when you want to set the URL.

so you should try with window.location.href
[What is the difference between document.location.href and document.location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652816/what-is-the-difference-between-document-location-href-and-document-location)