# Return value from Javascript to HTML <a href> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have html code like this:

```
<a id="abc_1" name="link_1" href=""
                    onclick="updateLink(this.id);">Test Link</a>
```

My Javascript function is like this:

```
function updateLink(a){ 
 var newurl = document.location.href "+" + a.valueOf();
 return newurl;
}
```

I want to direct the user to this newurl on click of link.
How to do it?
Note: I have seen an example with use of `<div>` tag, but I need it in `<a href>` tag.

Comment: `location.href = newurl`  should work

Comment: you aren't redirecting them with that function. like @tymeJV said you need to set the location.href of the page.

Comment: I removed return and tried location.href = newurl, but its not working, if I do alert(newurl), it shows the updated url but page is just getting refreshed.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I found out my mistake, I havent used href="#". Sorry I am new to web development and Thank a Lot

Comment: @User2403 That's correct, a link without an href does not get treated as a link https://jsfiddle.net/4n1rfwch/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the anchor attribute id or name contains information about the new URL.

Check out this example:

```
<a href="#" id="abc_1" name="link_1" onclick="updateLink(this)" >Test Link</a>

<script>
function updateLink(a) {
  var newurl = "";

  //You could retrieve the object name
  newurl = a.getAttribute("name");

  //Or, retrieve the id
  newurl = a.getAttribute("id");

  //redirect 
  location.href = newurl;
}
</script>
```

Comment: ya, it worked, but I am using document.location.href instead of location.href, can it be a problem?? Whats the difference?? I am new and want to know the best one to use

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652816/what-is-the-difference-between-document-location-href-and-document-location

Answer (score 1):

One way is to change the href attribute from the click handler

```js
    window.updateLink = function (a){
       // This won't work in this example because this frame
       // is set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
       // However, the error message displayed in the console is indication 
       // that it indeed tried to navigate to the URL I gave it 
       a.setAttribute('href', 'http://www.google.com?q=' + a.id);
    }
```

```html
<a href="#" id="http://www.google.com" onclick="updateLink(this)" >Test</a>
```

Comment: Ya, Its working fine. Even the suggestion by  tymeJV (in comments) is working. I too found out my mistake, I havent used href="#". Sorry I am new to web development and Thank a Lot.

Comment: It should be working, I added an example where I change the href, you'll see that the page reload (to a blank page)

Comment: @User2403 The case where you may want to use my solution instead is when you need something to work when JavaScript is disabled. You set the href to a page that doesn't require JavaScript and change it to a JS enabled URL from the click handler.

Comment: Yes, You are right, it was returning error message and I thought it was working