# Redirect users when validation fails

Tags: javascript, php

I am facing some problem validating my form using JS.

This is the HTML,

```
<form action="xyz.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="id1">Enter ID</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id1" id="id1">
  </div>
  <button onclick="validateID()" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And this is the JS,

```
<script>
  function validateID() {
    var id = document.getElementById("id1").value;
    var reg1 = new RegExp("^([0-9][0-9][0-9])$");

    if (!(reg1.test(id))) {
      document.location.href= "http://www.errorpage.com";
    }
  }
</script>
```

It is supposed to check the submitted form value against the regex and if the validation fails it has to redirect to an error page.

However, it doesn't redirect. When I put an alert() in place of `document.location.href= "http://www.errorpage.com";` it works.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you try window.location.href

Comment: i think its not about location.href. its because the button type is submit and form do that default thing and submit the form to xyz.php. thats why when he put alert. it works. just refer to my answer below

Comment: So needs to return 0; after location.href?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think its not about location.href. its because the button type is submit and form do the default thing and submit the form to xyz.php. thats why when he put alert(). it works

Change

```html
<button onclick="validateID()" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
```

to type button

```html
<button onclick="validateID()" type="button" name="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
```

or

use onsubmit="validateID()" in form tag and remove on click event from button

Answer (score 1):

Try **window.location.href** or **location.href**

The detailed reason: [What is the difference between document.location.href and document.location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652816/what-is-the-difference-between-document-location-href-and-document-location)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  function validateID() {

    var id = document.getElementById("id1").value;
    var reg1 = new RegExp("^([0-9][0-9][0-9])$");

    if (!(reg1.test(id))) {
        document.location.href = "http://www.errorpage.com";
        return true;
    }else{

          return false;
    }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="xyz.php" method="post" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();  validateID();">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="id1">Enter ID</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id1" id="id1">
  </div>
  <button  type="submit" name="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just curious, shouldn't the JS be after the `<form>`? EDIT: Okay, got it now! How does it work? Does the browser save the function validateID() to use it later when the button is clicked?

Comment: Hmm every time you submit your form its use validateID(); function.