# Why is this link url cut off?

Tags: javascript, html, url

I'm making a website and I'd like to open a detail view when someone clicks on a name in a list of contacts. I've got this code:

```
    row.onclick = function(){
        let location = `contacts/contact.html?name=` + data[i].LAST_NAME;
        console.log(location);
        document.location = location;
    }
```

The console prints out `contacts/contact?name=Dave` but the browser displays the url as just `contacts/contact` after the redirect. What's going on? Does this have anything to do with the fact that I'm running this off the local file system?

Comment: Are you using a local server? It sounds like a problem with URL rewriting.

Comment: FYI: do not use [document.location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652816/what-is-the-difference-between-document-location-href-and-document-location)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write to `location.href`.

```
row.onclick = function(){
    let location = `contacts/contact.html?name=` + data[i].LAST_NAME;
    console.log(location);
    window.location.href = location;
}
```